Two-way analog signal converter
To begin with: I have almost zero electrical/electronic knowledge.
I want to have something like two-way analog signal converter. On one side there is 0V-15V and on the other there is 0V-3.3V. The signal is analog.
The long story:
I have an entry phone that has a pair of wire (plus) and (minus). It's a simple analog DC signal.
The exemplary reading from oscilloscope (I do now own oscilloscope - I found it on the internet) of the signal of entry phone:

On the other side I have RaspberryPi Pico W with dedicated DAC/ADC but both are 3.3V digital logic.
I want to make RPi an interface, so I could connect entry phone to the Internet.

The image is too small to read.

I've put another, bigger image

Are you trying to generate analog phone signals on the RPI so that you can make or receive calls with the analog phone (PSTN)  through the internet with another such device?

Yes. I don't know if it's PSTN but seems like your description is correct. But I want to make it two way so I could talk over the Internet (like on a smartphone) when someone will call an entry phone.
